# "_user" & the use of underscore is this a shortcut?

Tags: php

I have been reading through some PHP code and I'm confused about one thing. I'm sorry if it may be basics, but I couldn't find anything about this (tbh no idea how to search for it).

there is a time where they use "_user". I have found out that it refers to class USER. However, I can't find anywhere where they refer _user to the USER class.

1. Does the underscore _ has a special meaning?
2. where and how did they link USER class with _user?

---

order.php file:

```
class ORDER
{
// order properties
private $_db = null;
private $_settings = null;
private $_user = null;

private $_userLevel = 1;

...

/**
 * Order Constructor
 * @param $db
 * @param $settings
 * @param $user
 * @param $need_db_record
 * @return ORDER
 */
public function __construct(&$db, &$settings, &$user, $need_db_record=false, $check_user_change = true)
{
    $this->_db = $db;
    $this->_settings = $settings;
    $this->_user = $user;
...
}


/**
 * Returns class instance
 * @return USER
 */
public function user()
{
    return $this->_user;
}
```

Comment: Where is the rest of the code?

Comment: underscore has not any special meaning. I am afraid it is impossible to answer your question without full code of your class in question.

Comment: It's sometimes used as a convention for `private` fields so they can have a matching magic getter without the underscore.

Answer (score -1):

1) Some people use an underscore before variable names to denote a private variable. This is just a convention though and has no effect on the functionality of the code. If you want to know more about visiblity of variables, see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php.

2) <s>This question can not be answered without us seeing more of the code. Somewhere in the class there is either a setter method for $_user or it gets set in the constructor of the class. Since it seems to be private, these are are the only two options.</s> <- More code was provided. New answer:

2) The variable $user is introduced via the constructor of the class ORDER. Somewhere in your code you will find the class USER, which describes how the object $user is built. If you want to know from where exactly $user is coming, search for "new Order(" in your code. You will find all places, where ORDER instances are created and you will see the arguments that are used. You can do the same with "new User(" and you will find all the places where USER instances are created.

If you are new to OOP I propose you read some introductory articles. You can start with the article from the PHP site itself: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php or look for some online courses or tutorials, like for example: https://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-bH5s3/0/1

An important aspect of the ORDER class you provided is that the variables $db, $settings and $user are given as references. That means if one would manipulate anything on the $db instance, these changes would be global. Chances are there is only one instance of $db, $settings and $user in the system, which are passed around by reference. See also: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: Hey, I updated the code to anything I could think that was relevant, but it's hard for me to know as I'm a little bit confused (first time trying to read OO PHP) and there is like 10 different files of over 5k lines. it also includes a comment saying that it "Returns class instance of USER" ... please note it wasn't me who voted down your answer